# Set up Cherokee + Web2py on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid

Tags: ubuntu, web2py, cherokee

Anyone have a script or set of instructions for setting up a fresh install of web2py on Cherokee on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid (in the cloud)? Lucid or Cherokee repositories OK. Sqlite fine for now but MySql or Postgres would be great.

Answer (score 1):

**update:** [Much more concise, direct instructions for the latest Cherokee](http://web2pyslices.com/main/slices/take_slice/110) ?from the question author?

---

**I just successfully set up Ubuntu 10.04 + Cherokee 0.99.39 + Web2Py 1.91.4.** It's set up on a [VPS](http://novps.com), but I suppose [setting it up on Amazon EC](http://www.scribd.com/doc/26436821/Howto-deploy-Web2py-on-amazon-Ec2) is not too different (compared to [setting up on a VPS](http://vimeo.com/10377947), the Web2py-specific steps are identical). Also, I wanted to use uWSGI, but [FastCGI is also an option](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#Cherokee-with-FastGGI). The latest version of Web2Py (1.90.1+) has [built-in support for MySql](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/msg/a1d95198f3ad4f34).

**Steps in brief:**

1. Provision VPS with Ubuntu 10.04
2. [Ensure "Universe" repositories are enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine).
3. Follow [these steps](http://vimeo.com/10377947) to run [this script](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/scripts/setup-web2py-ubuntu.sh?spec=svnd2d9570b84cf2afc439363f175c7575f8c75dd23&r=d2d9570b84cf2afc439363f175c7575f8c75dd23) that installs Web2Py and related dependencies.
4. The script above actually installed Apache2 webserver. [Uninstall/disable Apache2](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=373387).
5. Install Cherokee web server. I simply used [`sudo apt-get install cherokee`](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-cherokee-web-server-with-mysql-php-support-on-jaunty.html)
6. [Install uWSGI](http://goshawknest.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/install-uwsgi-on-ubuntu-10-10/).
7. [Configure uWSGI for Web2Py](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example#Web2Py2uWSGI).
8. Configure a Cherokee virtual server to use a uWSGI+Web2Py platform. ([Jump to step III](http://web2pyslices.com/main/slices/take_slice/64))

**Optional:**
The pretty Cherokee admin graphs don't work without some [additional steps](http://code.google.com/p/cherokee/issues/detail?id=702) (install rddtools and libcherokee-mod-rrd; *wait 5-10 minutes*)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://web2pyslices.com/main/slices/take_slice/64) may be what you're looking for. [Here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#Cherokee-with-FastGGI) is another.

Comment: Yes, I've seen those. Sorry, should have mentioned I wanted to use uWSGI. The web2pyslices one is pretty good but slightly outdated.